# How do you add subdomains to .local on Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, networking, osx-snow-leopard

I've got servername.local working both locally and from other office computers.  I've got subdomain.servername.local working locally but I can't figure out how to get that working from other office computers (local network).

And idea how to do this on snow leopard?

Answer (score 2):

I set up an internal DNS server for this purpose. It responds to all requests in a `.sj` psuedo-TLD and passes on non-`.sj` requests to Google's public DNS.

It's a more complex initial setup, but you only have to configure new domains in one place (the server), and there's no configuration step for the client computers.

Comment: I recommend this approach too. Use a DNS server, make up your own fake TLD, and leave .local for Bonjour.

Answer (score 1):

Add the entries to `/etc/hosts`

So add `123.123.123.123 somedomain.blah.local` to the file.

OR: Setup a DNS server in your office that is the primary, and then setup a zone file for the `.local` TLD.

Comment: Note that this would have to be done on each computer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) It's a lightweight way to serve up local domain names.

[Here's a quick rundown](http://inspirix.wikispaces.com/dnsmasq-on-OSX) on how to install and configure it using [Darwin Ports](http://darwinports.com/)